# How to activate this effect on a picture (CSS, HTML)?

Tags: html, css, image, web, effect

I'm tring to have an effect on a picture in my website, the effect is "Image revealing from text on hover
" from [this website](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-image-effects/).
I made a CSS file with this code:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #E3DFD2
}

effecrforthelogo {
    background: url('http://www.uploads.co.il/uploads/images/607163485.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40vmin;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 30vmin auto;
}

text {
    font-size: 10px;
    transition: font-size .4s ease-out;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: arial;
}

effectforthelogo:hover text {
    transition: font-size .4s ease-in;
    font-size: 300px;
}
```

and in my aspx file of the page in my wesite I wrote this HTML code:

```
    <efectforthelogo viewbox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50">
      <defs>
        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="49">
          <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" fill="#fff"/>
          <text x="20" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">S</text>
          <text x="25" id="ltrV" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">V</text>
          <text x="30" text-anchor="middle" y="50" dy="0">G</text>
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="49" height="49" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="1" fill="#E3DFD2"/>
    </efectforthelogo>
```

All it shows is "SVG" on the top of the page, without the picture/the effect.
Please help!

I wanted to see the picture woth the effect, but it only showd the text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please check your spelling - what is effecrforthelogo for example, and why isn't the tag an svg rather than a custom one?

Comment: Even if I copy the exact code it doesn't work, please help